# Resolve jQuery deferred with a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

According to [the promise resolution procedure](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#the_promise_resolution_procedure) of Promises/A+ specification it is
possible to resolve a deferred with a promise.

For example in [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) library you just do:

```
deferred.resolve(promise);
```

Whether the implementation of promises bundled with jQuery supports this? I tried the same with jQuery and it treats promise just as an immediate value.

Comment: Can you include some code that lead you to this conclusion?

Comment: Well, if you tried it and it didn't work then no, they do not support it.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/

Comment: IIRC jQuery didn't implement promises that match the Promisies/A+ spec. Because they didn't initially they can't now without introducing incompatibility.

Comment: @AlexShilman Here is the code to get some insight - https://github.com/ilyai/pg-queries/blob/master/index.js#L103:L115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whether the implementation of promises bundled with jQuery supports this?

No. jQuery is not [Promise/A+](http://promisesaplus.com/)-compliant.

However, notice that the spec is only about `then` and the promises returned by it, it does not mention Deferreds or how to resolve them. jQuery does indeed support assimilation of promises returned from a `.then()` callback (since V1.8, at least).

Comment: Trying to resolve a deferred with a promise also hints at [you might be doing something wrong](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).